# Angular2 - I'm using router.navigate - when I change route it jumps back to original route?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

Angular2 - I'm using router.navigate - when I change route it jumps back to original route?

My app works fine.
But on login I want to redirect the user to the logged in dashboard.
But when it visits the dashboard view it then returns to login view again.

**This is my code so far:**

```
  this.router.navigate('/Dashboard');
```

All the routes work fine by using router-link etc but I need the login.ts file to do the redirect on success of login.

**This is my Login.is file:**

```
 import {Component, View, CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgIf} from 'angular2/angular2';
 import {Router, RouterLink, RouterOutlet} from 'angular2/router';
 import {AuthService} from '../../services/authService';
 import {User} from '../../models/user';
 import {Dashboard} from '../home/home';

 @Component({
   selector: 'Login',  
   providers: [AuthService, User]
 })

 @View({
   templateUrl: '/src/app/components/login/login.html',
   directives: [RouterOutlet, RouterLink, CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgIf],
 })

 export class Login {
   authService:AuthService;
   user: User;
   error: string = null;
   router: Router;

   constructor(router: Router, authService: AuthService, user: User){   
       this.authService = authService;
       this.user = user;
       this.router = router;
   }

   logIn = () => {  
        this.authService.logIn(this.user).then((response) => {
             if(response === false)
                this.error = "Incorrect login details";
             else
                this.router.navigate(['/Dashboard']);
        });       
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this.

Solution was: a naming issue with the route config in app.ts. I had the names not matching for the routes.